# XCTest get order of execution from tests run in random order

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest

As title says. I run my tests in random order, but sometimes one or several tests fail. To reproduce this I would like to run the tests in the same order. But how do I get the order from the tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, Apple has provided no way for us to reproduce the same order. This makes it impossible for us to take full advantage of randomized test order.

They say, "File a Radar." Here's my Open Radar filing if you'd like to copy it: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4953802914398208